# Why in exposed WSDL of Web Service, <include> tag is changed to an <import> tag

Tags: xml, maven, soap, apache-camel, wsdl

I'm new in SOAP and I'm developing a hello world web service using Camel and Springboot.

In the WSDL file of my service I'm using `<xsd:include>` to refer to my XSD file

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://com/blog/demo/webservices/accountservice" >
        <xsd:include namespace="http://com/blog/demo/webservices/accountservice"
                     xmlns="http://com/blog/demo/webservices/accountservice" 
                     schemaLocation="../schema/AccountService.xsd">
        </xsd:include>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

When I run the service, in the exposed WSDL the `<xsd:include>` tag is changed to `<xsd:import>`

```
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8090/soap-api/service/accounts?wsdl=AccountService.wsdl" namespace="http://www.briansdevblog.com/Accounts/"> </wsdl:import>
```

I'd like to know why this happens and how can I avoid this behavior

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.briansdevblog</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot-cxf-soap-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>  
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <cxf.version>3.3.2</cxf.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>     
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>                   
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/Accounts.wsdl</wsdl>                               
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>      
    </build>    
</project>
```